# Parse JSON and change my model without blocking UI

Tags: iphone, ios, json, cocoa, asihttprequest

I am writing an application that makes a lot of http requests and then parses their JSON response.

I want to parse the JSON asynchronously so as to avoid blocking the User Interface. 
After parsing, the Model should be changed according to the JSON received.
My ViewControllers are Key-Value-Observing my Model Classes, so as to refresh instantly.

My question is: Is it safe to parse the JSON and change my model in a background thread? When the model changes UI updates will be fired. I would really really like to avoid using locks because it will be too complicated for me. Is my solution safe? Any ideas on how to parse asynchronously and change the model safely without using threads at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write your own locks. Just use atomic properties in your model and you're threadsafe.

### Edit

Yes, that is what properties do: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2

Comment: If 2 different threads are writing on the same variable, is still atomic the only thing i have to do so as to be thread safe?

Comment: I change the model from a background thread. Then the view controllers will be informed about this because they are KVObserving the model. The User Interface updates will be guaranteed to be executed on the MainThread? Or not?

Comment: Based on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282709/kvo-rocks-now-how-do-i-use-it-asynchronously/1282820#1282820 I would say NO. But you can use `performSelectorOnMainThread` to update your UI to be safe. Or you do also switch to Notifications like in the mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic properties are NOT thread safe!
[Objective-C: Atomic, properties, threading and/or custom setter/getter](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/13/objectivce-c-atomic-properties-threading-andor-custom-settergetter/)
And from the [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html):

> Properties are atomic by default so that synthesized accessors provide robust access to properties in a multithreaded environment—that is, the value returned from the getter or set via the setter is always fully retrieved or set regardless of what other threads are executing concurrently.

This does NOT mean they are thread safe.

The [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) shows how to implement different kinds of locks.

But to answer your question about wether it is safe to parse json and update your model in the background: yes, it is. But the rest of your code that accesses model objects should be prepared for it. If you are handling merge notifications you should largely be fine, especially if your application uses fetched results controllers. If you have UI that is not driven by fetched results controllers, have your view controllers listen for the appropriate NSManagedObjectContext notifications (i.e. NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification) and act accordingly. You can use that to see when an object has been inserted, updated, etc. and then refresh your view controller by refetching the object by it's objectID. 
So when your json parsing in the background updates model objects, you get the merge notification and merge into the main thread's object context. Then your view controllers will see the changes in the notifications they are listening for, and boom, magically updated UI.